# Respawner not resetting database

Tags: .net, xunit

I'm having trouble using [Respawner](https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn) and I'm doing something wrong I just don't understand what that is.
When I run these tests, one of the two randomly fails with `Duplicate key` error.
I have been messing around with moving the "Reset" around and awaiting it. But even if I put it IN the test it still fails.

I have a Fixture

```
public sealed class FooFixture : IAsyncLifetime {
    private readonly MsSqlTestcontainer _msSqlTestContainer;
    private Respawner _respawner = default!;

    public FooFixture() {
        _msSqlTestContainer = new TestcontainersBuilder<MsSqlTestcontainer>().WithDatabase(new MsSqlTestcontainerConfiguration {
                                                                                                                                   Password = "Toeter01!"
                                                                                                                               })
                                                                             .Build();
    }

    public string ConnectionString { get; private set; } = default!;
    public SqlConnection Connection { get; private set; } = default!;

    public Task Reset() => _respawner.ResetAsync(Connection);

    public async Task InitializeAsync() {
        await _msSqlTestContainer.StartAsync();

        var sqlConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(_msSqlTestContainer.ConnectionString) {TrustServerCertificate = true};
        ConnectionString = sqlConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
        Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        await Connection.OpenAsync();
        _respawner = await Respawner.CreateAsync(Connection,
                                                 new RespawnerOptions {
                                                                          DbAdapter = DbAdapter.SqlServer,
                                                                          SchemasToInclude = new[] {"dbo"},
                                                                          CommandTimeout = 60
                                                                      });
        await Connection.ExecuteAsync(@"CREATE TABLE dbo.bar (foo int NOT NULL UNIQUE);");
    }

    public async Task DisposeAsync() {
        await _msSqlTestContainer.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

A Collection

```
[CollectionDefinition(nameof(FooCollection))]
public class FooCollection : ICollectionFixture<FooFixture> {
}
```

And simple test:

```
[Collection(nameof(FooCollection))]
[Trait("Category", "Integration")]
public class RespawnTest : IAsyncLifetime {
    private readonly FooFixture _fixture;

    public RespawnTest(FooFixture fixture) {
        _fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task One() {
        await _fixture.Connection.ExecuteAsync("INSERT INTO dbo.bar (foo) values (1) ");
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Two() {
        await _fixture.Connection.ExecuteAsync("INSERT INTO dbo.bar (foo) values (1) ");
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync() => await _fixture.Reset();

    public Task DisposeAsync() => Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: The respawner link is dead

Comment: I have just updated the link thank you!

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but why use this library? Why not destroy and create a new database for every test?

Comment: Because that's a lot more performance impact. It's how I'm doing it now, as I could not get this to work. But it's slowing down the test runs significantly